# Filter list according to given Object's fields (which could be null)

Tags: java, filtering

Is there any sophisticated way to filter through a list of objects when I have a FilterObject..

```
public class FilterListOfBets {
    private final String userId;
    private final long betId;
    private final int minBetTime;
    private final int maxBetTime;
    // constructor and get methods ..
}
```

.. and a list of bets containing all of the fields, so ..

```
public class Bet {
    private final long betId;
    private final String userId;
    private final long betTime;
}
```

.. the thing is that some (if not all) of FilterListObject's fields may be set to null. The result depends on the fields that have been set.
In the end I want to have a List filteredList which contains all the Objects that match the criteria.

If I, for instance, knew which values are set, I'd just loop through the list:

```
for (Bet bet : listOfBets) {
    if (betFilter.getUserId == bet.getUserId && betFilter.getBetId == bet.getBetId && ...)     
}
```

if minBetTime and maxBetTime in FilterListOfBets would be set, then the outcome list should also satisfy : minTime < time < maxTime.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object that you want to compare against and then use something like guava fluentiterable or java stream

```
FluentIterable.from(listOfObject)
    .filter(new Predicate<FilterObject>(FilterObject item) {
        return item.equals(myTestItem);
    })
    .toList();
```

I have written this on my phone so havnt checked it but hopefully you get the idea

Comment: How would I however compare time, when FilterObject has minimum and maximum time, then the outcome list should also satisfy the condition where the time is minTime < time < maxTime. The object to create would still have a static time, which could miss all in the list of bets to compare.

Comment: Sorry I missed that part. I would maybe use the comparedTo call by adding a comparator. Or simply define your own comparedWith function in FilterObject and use that in the predicate instead